# JsonObject("body") not a string

Tags: java, json

I do see a issue with json.org version 2.3. The same problem does not observe with json.org 2.2 in java

Following is a raw message

```
"message" : { "header" : {"version" : "1.2" },
              "body"   : {"event" : "plan"}
            }
JSONObject msgJsonObject = new JSONObject(rawMessage.getBody());
String message = msgJsonObject.getString(MESSAGE);
JSONObject bodyJsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
log.error(" Message : "+ message);


String body = bodyJsonObject.getString("body");
```

with json.org version 2.2 above code works fine but with json.org version 2.3 'bodyJsonObject.getString(BODY)' raises JsonException: JsonObject("body") not a string.

Could you please let me know why its an issue with version 2.3?

Comment: `{"event" : "plan"}` is not a string, it's a JSON object

Comment: try String body = bodyJsonObject.getJSONObject"body").toString(); as it will not consider directly as string from json object

Comment: The official "json.org" library uses dates as its version identifiers.  What do you mean by "2.2" and "2.3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `body`, `{"event" : "plan"}` is not a string: it's a JSON object.

I do not know why the behaviour of your JSON library has changed between versions 2.2 and 2.3, but the behaviour in 2.3 seems correct.

If you want to get a `String` representation of the object, you might try:

```
bodyJsonObject.getJSONObject("body").toString();
```